# Check if an array key in a field exists in mongo

Tags: php, mongodb

```
{
 "_id": ObjectId("502626aad4ebdf600b000000"),
 "created_at": ISODate("2012-08-11T09: 32: 26.0Z"),
 "excerpt": "lotto results for August 11, 2012",
 "results": {
    "1-digit" : {
        "0" : "1",
    },
    "2-digit" : {
        "0" : "1",
        "1" : "2",
    },
    "3-digit" : {
        "0" : "1",
        "1" : "2",
        "2" : "3",
    }
    }
}
```

How should I check if `results.1-digit` exists?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can run query `{results.1-digit : {$exists : true }}`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Aha! Thanks. Would this result to a slow query though?

Comment: You will need to add sparse index on field you want to check for $exists, then it will be fast.

Comment: You can find additional information here http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-sparse%3Atrue

Answer (score 1):

Adding quotes are as important in shell I believe

```
{"results.1-digit" : {$exists : true }}
```